# Hygieia: Issue under github widget- cant see anything under Repo Type

Tags: hygieia

I have installed hygieia in my aws machine. After installing hygieia i am trying to configure github widget. But under repo type i dont find to select github.

Furthermore Please find the jar commmand.

```
java -jar github-collector.jar --spring.config.name=github --spring.config.location=/usr/Hygieia/collectors/scm/github/application.properties
```

Thanks
Trinath

Comment: Hope you have added the configuration setting required in the application.properties file as mentioned here: https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia/blob/gh-pages/pages/hygieia/collectors/scm/github.md#sample-application-properties-file

Answer (score 0):

What version of hygieia are you using?. If you are using old version, upgrade to  Hygieia latest version.

https://hygieia.github.io/hygieia/newUI.html

Download the GitHub collector from [Hygieia GitHub Page](https://hygieia.github.io/hygieia/collectors.html)

Follow the below document for configure GitHub in Hygieia Team and Product dashboard

[Click Here](https://hygieia.github.io/hygieia/product_view.html)

Thank you.